# Stream Vs. Iterator in entrySet of a Map - Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, iterator, java-stream, entryset

To my understanding, the following code should have print `true`, since both `Stream` and `Iterator` are pointing to the first element.

However, when I ran the following code it is printing `false`:

```
final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", "B");
final Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map).entrySet();
Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 = set.iterator().next();
Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 = set.stream().findFirst().get();
System.out.println(entry1 == entry2);
```

What could be the reason for this different behavior?

Comment: No, they shouldn't, since a HashMap's entrySet has no ordering.

Comment: @JBNizet-- Agreed, But I have only 1 element in my map Sir.

Comment: Maps also make no guarantee that they don't create new Map.Entry instances on the fly. Don't compare objects with ==. Use equals().

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet. use "entry1.equals(entry2)"

Comment: @Eran-- Are you expert in English Language too...:D very good edits...(Y)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Both entries are referring to the same logical entry of your Map (whose key is "A" and value is "B"). However, they are not the same instance.

If you dig deep enough in the implementation of `Collections.unmodifiableMap(map)` you'll see that iterating over the `entrySet` of the map returned by `Collections.unmodifiableMap(map)` returns a new `Map.Entry` which wraps the original modifiable entry:

```
public Map.Entry<K,V> next() {
  return new UnmodifiableEntry<>(i.next());
}
```

I'm assuming a new instance `Map.Entry` instance is also created when you call `set.stream().findFirst().get()`, so the two methods return different instances.

Even if you'll call the same method twice you'll get difference instances, i.e. the following code will also print `false`:

```
Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 = set.iterator().next();
Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 = set.iterator().next();
System.out.println(entry1 == entry2);
```

On the other hand, if you obtain the entry directly from the original `HashMap`, you will get `true`:

```
Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 = map.entrySet ().iterator().next();
Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 = map.entrySet ().stream().findFirst().get();
System.out.println (entry1==entry2);
```

If this case the entry is not wrapped by a new instance, so both `entrySet ().iterator().next()` and `entrySet ().stream().findFirst().get()` return the same instance.

Comment: Kudos for finding that line in next(). I did some searching too, but gave up to quickly. Fixed the messy indenting btw ;-)

Comment: Great finding. Seems like this question has nothing to do with stream vs iterator, however, it is related to unmodifiableMap implementation.

Answer (score 12):

The thing is:

```
Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 = set.iterator().next();
Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 = set.stream().findFirst().get();
```

You are not comparing the **values** you put into the map. But **Entry** objects!

In other words: it looks like your code is creating **new** Entry objects using your code. It is completely up to the *internal* implementation of that unmodifiable Map/Set what to return when it is asked for an iterator or a stream ... and as Eran was a bit quicker to lookup: the reason is that **new** Entry objects are created when *iterating*.

So, when using `equals()` instead of `==` ... you get the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

No both `entry1` and `entry2` are has same value but they are not pointing the same object because the each time you get the `Map.Entry` object it create new one.
Look at the below code :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("A", "B");
        final Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map).entrySet();
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 = set.iterator().next();
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 = set.stream().findFirst().get();
        System.out.println("entry1 : " + System.identityHashCode(entry1));
        System.out.println("entry2 : " + System.identityHashCode(entry2));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("directly for set " + i + " : " + System.identityHashCode(set.stream().findFirst().get()));
        }
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
entry1 : 1283928880
entry2 : 295530567
directly for set 0 : 2003749087
directly for set 1 : 1324119927
directly for set 2 : 990368553
directly for set 3 : 1096979270
directly for set 4 : 1078694789
```

`System.identityHashCode()` will give hash code.