# Recursive list function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am currently working on this program in Haskell where I analyze a website and try to find all links (href) that belong to this website. I was already able to extract all the links of the main site but i am struggling with the recursion since i want to follow the links I already found and do the same process again.

This is what i have already:

```
parseHtml = fmap LB.unpack . simpleHttp
filterFunc x y = -- damn long line with a lot of filters

main :: IO()
main = do
    let site = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    url <- parseHtml site
    let links = filterFunc site url
    mapM_ print $ take 5 $ links
```

And this is my output so far:

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/company/about"
"https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here"
"https://stackoverflow.com/help"
"https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/directory/developer-jobs"
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691577/stream-versus-iterators-in-set"
```

I just need a hint on how to further proceed and how to visit the already found links again. Should I work with fold?

Answer (score 1):

Link finding is essentially a graph traversal problem, which can be tricky in Haskell because of functional purity: it's hard to explicitly mark nodes (links) as visited or not through the use of an external history table.

Your typical traversal algorithm might look something like this:

```
function traverse(current_node) {
    if (current_node.is_visited) {
        return some_data;
    } else {
        current_node.is_visisted = true;          // Hard in Haskell!
        accumulated_data = ...;
        for (child in current_node.children()) {
            accumulated_data += traverse(child);  // Recursion happens here.
        }
        return accumulated_data;
    }
}
```

Because there is not an easy, direct way to mark a node as visited or not, we can try other solutions. For instance, we might consider something of the sort:

```
traverse :: ([URL], Data) -> URL -> ([URL], Data)
traverse (history, datum) current = let ... in ([new_history], accumulated_data)
```

The idea here is as follows: we keep an explicit list of `URL`s that we have visited. This allows us to quickly return from the current node (`URL`) if it appears in our history list (perhaps a `Set` for optimization? :)). In this case, each subsequent call to a child node using `traverse` would get the `new_history` list, effectively keeping track of a list of visited and unvisisted `URL`s.

One possible way to implement this is using a fold function such as `foldl`:

```
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

Here type `t a` might be `[URL]`, that denotes the children of the current link, and our `traverse` function conveniently has the type signature `(b -> a -> b)`, where `type b = ([URL], Data)` and `type a = URL`.

Can you take it from here and figure out how to combine `traverse` and `foldl`?

Comment: You may want to use a `Set URL` instead of `[URL]`. Both for efficiency and because this is what you mean when you keep around that list.

Comment: I have this code snippet in my filterfunc `Set.toList . Set.fromList` to get rid of all the duplicates i get. Should i just keep it as a set to make it easier to work with it?

Comment: Keeping it as a `Set` is probably the easiest option, as @gallais has pointed out. Another thing to watch out for is that links with different names may point to the same page, so it is probably wise to also get a canonical representation for them.

Comment: If for some reason you need to keep unique representations in `List` format, one option is to use `List.nub`:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your link visiting logic in a separate function which takes a link as a parameter, and then recurse on the links, as you intuited.

Depending on what you want to ultimately do with the links, you can for instance simply fold the links with your function.

For example, slightly modifying your code:

```
parseHtml = fmap LB.unpack . simpleHttp
filterFunc x y = -- damn long line with a lot of filters

visitLink :: String -> IO ()
visitLink site = do
    url <- parseHtml site
    let links = filterFunc site url
    mapM_ print $ take 5 $ links -- or whatever you want to do on your links
    mapM_ visitLink links -- the recursive call


main :: IO()
main = visitLinks "https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

If, rather than printing the links as you go, you would rather for instance return them, tweak the return type of the `visitLink` function (for instance `String -> IO [String]` and change your last line in `visitLink` suitably (for instance `fmap join $ mapM visitLinks links`).

As mentionned in another answer, keep in mind that with such a simple code, you may visit the same link infinitely many times. Consider storing the links you visit in a suitable data structure (such as a set) that you would pass to `visitLink`.

Comment: I only printed them to make sure everything is working and to see what the outcome is so i know how to work with it. The last step would be to save all the links i get into a file.

Comment: And i forget to say that i'm using a Set in my filterfunc (Set.toList . Set.fromList) to get rid of all the duplictaes

Comment: @SarahK. sure, what I meant is that the solution I propose works for everything that fits in an `IO ()` (including writing for a file), but you may have to adapt it for other usages. Regarding my Set comment, keep in mind that a later page can refer to a former one (for instance a page linking to the home page of the site) and you need to take this into account.